# Inconsistent Results When Using Cookies for logging in

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, twitter

I am trying to look into how cookies work, and in particular, I tried logging into <s>twitter</s> X by using my and a few other accounts, but the success seems random, even though I use the same PC, browser, and extension (that copies and pastes cookies). Some cookies work flawlessly (log in right after you refresh the page) but some do nothing at all. Is there something that I am missing? As far as I know, they should all work fine, given that other accounts that I use all belong to people I know and they don't get kicked out when they turn their pc off or close the tab, meaning that (in my mind at least) their cookies work fine.